# Submit a mass query of latitude and longitudes to soilgrid for data download

Tags: soilgrids

I would like to obtain soil physicochemical data for >500 sites for a study I'm doing for my dissertation research in the pacific northwest of the US. I have latitude and longitude for each site, and would like to query soilgrids with these latitude and longitudes to download the soil physical and chemical data wherever they are available.

I tried using the Explore tool on the map, and can click on individual locations and see the data are available. When I try to download a 2x2 degree tile using the download tool, I get a tif file. It would be ideal to be able to download a dataframe that includes the numerical values for all physical and chemical soil properties by latitude and longitude for multiple sites.

Is this possible with soilgrids? If not, are there any suggestions for other databases that I may query for these data instead?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a script that queries the API with your locations. https://rest.soilgrids.org/

Or it looks like there is an R package for data access.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GSIF/GSIF.pdf

Comment: Current https://rest.soilgrids.org is closing at the end of this week (25th June), and it uses the old soilgrids v1 data (discontinued). You can read about it [here](https://www.isric.org/news/soilgrids-version-2017-services-communication). The GBIF package is using the above rest link and will become inactive by such date.

Answer (score 1):

As the name implies, SoilGrids provides a collection of grids, not data frames. Personally I am not familiar with any standard for the exchange of data frames.

At this moment, the simplest way to query these maps programatically is through the [WCS service](https://www.isric.org/web-coverage-services-wcs). There is also a small collection of [notebooks](https://git.wur.nl/isric/soilgrids/soilgrids.notebooks) with examples using OWSLib.